# Linq query in stored procedure result set Ado.Net

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have a stored procedure with multiple joins, pulling all the data into a resultset I.e in dataset, now I want to write a linq query over it. How can I do that?

I am expecting:

```
IEnumerable<SomeType> result;
```

[where I need to know how the Properties of SomeType are defined.]

This is what I have tried but it does not look efficient.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select top 10 * from trade"); 
cmd.Connection = con; 

if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open) 
{ 
    con.Open(); 
}   

SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); 
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 

dt.Load(dr); 
var result = dt.AsEnumerable(); 

string valresukir = string.Empty; 

var sortResult = result.OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x["trade_num"]) > 12); 
string valuedata = string.Empty; 

foreach (var i in sortResult) 
{ 
    valuedata += i["trade_num"].ToString(); 
}
```

Comment: In simple words i want to loop to all the rows of rowcollection and create a generic collection of some Type...Like the above example we can easily do it by defining a class as trade and loop it one by one and add it to the List...do i have to create a class for store proc or EF does it automatically? and How

Answer (score 0):

to can write linq query on data table like

```
var data= from dataRow in dt.AsEnumerable()
          where dataRow.Field<int>("trade_num") > 12
          select dataRow
```

if `trade_num` is integer . Take it as a example and add your conditions accordingly.

Hope it will help you.